# Background from Animation not rendering

Tags: rendering

I just need help on rendering this animation, where the background picture just doesn't show up when rendering. Can someone help me? I'll send pictures.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in your second screenshot, you didn't enable transparency for your render. The **Transparent** checkbox is under `Render Properties > Film`.

[image: Transparent]